# Destructuring fails on type depending on generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have these 2 interfaces:

```
export interface Converter<T> {
  decode?: Decoder<T>;
  encode?: Encoder<T>;
  notify?: Notifier<T>;
  type?: T;
}

export interface Api {
  state: Converter<State>;
  water: Converter<Water>;
  version: Converter<Versions>;
}
```

In this class I make use of these interfaces. Particularly, I have a function called `write` where I make sure the the parameter `name` is a key of the `Api` interface and the `value` is the corresponding `Generic` of that key.

```
export default class Characteristic {
  private api: Api;

  public async write<Name extends keyof Api, Value = Api[Name]["type"]>(
    name: Name,
    value: Value
  ): Promise<void> {
    const { encode } = this.api[name];
    const buffer = encode(value);
    //                    ^^^^^
  }
}
```

This pattern works as expected, but here I get an error on `value` that I don't quite understand:

> ```
> Type '"sleep" | "goingToSleep" | "idle" | "busy" | "espresso" | "steam" | "hotWater" | "shortCal" | "selfTest" | "longCal" | "descale" | "fatalError" | "init" | "noRequest" | "skipToNext" | ... 7 more ... | Versions' is not assignable to type 'Value'.
>   '"sleep" | "goingToSleep" | "idle" | "busy" | "espresso" | "steam" | "hotWater" | "shortCal" | "selfTest" | "longCal" | "descale" | "fatalError" | "init" | "noRequest" | "skipToNext" | ... 7 more ... | Versions' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Value', but 'Value' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
>     Type '"sleep"' is not assignable to type 'Value'.
>       '"sleep"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Value', but 'Value' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'
> ```

Comment: I think that once you make this into a [mcve] that runs in a standalone IDE, you'll find that this issue is because of TypeScript's lack of support for what I've been calling ["correlated types"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You will probably want to use a type assertion to suppress the error, but for now I can't reproduce your issue (missing definitions) so I can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

I think Typescript is complaining about the lack of constraints on `Value` here. You give it a default value, but it could be still overridden to a different type.

Do you need to make the `Value` type generic there? You could change the method signature like this:

```js
public async write<Name extends keyof Api>(
  name: Name,
  value: Api[Name]["type"]
): Promise<void> {
```

Optionally add a type helper to make it look neater:

```js
type ValueFor<Name extends keyof Api> = Api[Name]["type"];
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, that is true, it simplifies things, but it does not change the problem.

Comment: Can you make a typescript-playground demonstration of the issue?